# escape character headache

Tags: c#, escaping

I am trying to use c# to find an html element however I am struggling with the escape characters. My code below is taking an html and trying to find an element within it however start is not returning the IndexOf. What am I doing wrong?

```
//html im trying to find <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cbParent" summary="Results from your search" id="searchResultsTbl">

        string table = "<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" class=\"cbParent\" summary=\"Results from your search\" id=\"searchResultsTbl\">";
        int start = html.IndexOf(table);
```

Comment: Why you are not using ' ' instead of " " ?

Comment: I have tried   string table = @"<table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" class=""cbParent"" summary=""Results from your search"" id=""searchResultsTbl"">"; with no joy

Comment: It is likely the real problem is you are using string manipulation when you should probably be using a library capable of dealing with an HTML DOM -- one where you could use, ohh, some sort of XPath or CSS-selector to find the element based on, say, the ID. If IndexOf doesn't match it doesn't match and is unrelated to the escape character (except as how you think a string literal is being turned into a string object). Perhaps what you are trying to match has a <tab> instead of a <space> in one spot? Oops. If the document is XML-compliant then XDocument or XmlDocument are really easy to use.

Comment: Can you post more of the code?  Are you absolutely certain that the string is in 'html'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use single quotes in place of double quotes

```
"<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='cbParent' summary='Results from your search' id='searchResultsTbl'>"
```

**Explanation:**
Html attributes may have single quotes `' '` or double quotes `" "`

Comment: The html been returned contains double quotes. Does this matter?

Comment: This is a clean way of representing this. However, because it's an IndexOf (which is another issue entirely!) it changes the semantics slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
path = @"c:\mypath\temp.dir"
```

to use it verbatim. Use double quotes twice to escape it

```
s = @"Say ""Hello"""
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure it's in the `html` string?

You can also try placing a `@` before the string literal, in which case a double-quote would be accomplished with `""` instead of `\"`.

Comment: Hi David, Yes its an entire html page. I had tried using @ before but it didnt seem to help

Comment: This (verbatim strings) will just change `\"` constructs to `""` -- not sure that's an improvement.